# How to prove the following inequality when k > 10?

Tags: inequality

Let's say we have $n \in \Bbb N$ and $n \geq 10$, we need to prove the following with proof to back down:

$2^n \geq 100n$

I've tried the following:

- First I proved the first term of the inequality $n_ 0 = 10$, which holds
- Then I set $k$ to be another term, and $k \gt n_0$, so $k \gt 10$
- I attempted to prove that $k+1$ holds too.

I tried to prove $k+1$ by replacing $k$ with $k+1$ in the expression in order to get back to the expression with $k$, as such:

$2^{k+1} \gt 100(k+1)$

$2^{k+1} \gt 100k + 100$

But we have $2^k > 100k$, so:

$2^{k+1} - 2^k \gt 100$

$2^{k} > 100$

And then I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help?

Comment: You are done, what more do you want ?

Comment: The inequality after "so:" is not justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction.
Case $n=10$:
We have that $2^{10}=1024 \geq 100 \cdot 10=1000$.
General case:
Supose that $k \geq 10$ and $2^{k} \geq 100 \cdot k$ then we have that:
$k+1 \geq 10$ and:
$2^{k+1}=2^{k} \cdot 2 \geq 100 \cdot k \cdot 2 = 100 \cdot (k+k) \geq 100 \cdot (k+1)$

Comment: Thank you sir, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $2^k > 100k$, right?  You can multiply the left hand side and right hand side with 2, giving you
$$ 2 \cdot2^k > 2 \cdot 100k, $$ which is equivalent to saying that
$$ 2^{k+1} > 2 \cdot 100k.$$
But then you should notice that $ 2 \cdot 100k$ is bigger than $100 \cdot (k+1)$, as  $ 2 \cdot 100k = 100k + 100k \geq 100k + 100$.  Therefore you have
$$ 2 \cdot2^k > 2 \cdot 100k \geq 100(k+1), $$

so you're done.

Alternative approach:
This is equivalent to showing that $2^n -100n \geq 0$.

For $n=10$ we get $$2^10-100\cdot10 = 1024 -1000 =24 \geq 0.$$ So it hold true for $n=10$.

Of course, we could also view the expression $2^n- 100*n$ as a function on the real line ( but it just happens to be that you're only interested in the natural numbers). So we can say $f(x)= 2^x -100x$.  Differentiating this function gives $$f'(x) = 2^x \log(x) -100 $$.  The derivative is clearly always bigger than zero for $x >10$, so the function $f(x)$ is increasing for $x>10$.
But since we had that $f(10)>0$, it means that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>10$.

In particular this means that $2^n -100n \geq 0$  for all $n>10$, which proves the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove $$2^n\ge100n\implies2^{n+1}\ge100(n+1).$$

You can write

$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n=2\cdot100n=100n+100n\ge100n+100.$$